# ASP.NET MVC Complex model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

> I’m trying to use complex object types in ASP.NET MVC Model binding. I
>   need to insert and update student records with exam results

```
public class InitialApplicantLevel2Model
    {
        public InitialApplicantLevel2Model()
        {
            alResults = new ALResults();
        }

        public int InitialApplicantLevel2ID { get; set; }
        public int? IntakeID { get; set; }
        public string ApplicantName { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }

        public string NIC { get; set; }
        public string Passport { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }

        public ALResults alResults { get; set; }

     }

    public class ALResults
    {
        public int ResultsID { get; set; }
        public int InitialApplicantLevel2ID { get; set; }
        public string Stream { get; set; }
        public string Grading { get; set; }
        public string IndexNo { get; set; }
        public int? Year { get; set; }
        public int? Attempt { get; set; }
        public double? ZScore { get; set; }
        public string Medium { get; set; }
    }
```

Repository class Create new record

```
public bool Create(InitialApplicantLevel2Model model)
        {
            try
            {
                using (context = new SIMSDBAPPEntities())
                {
                    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        tblInitialApplicantLevel2 tb = new tblInitialApplicantLevel2();
                        tb.NIC = model.NIC;
                        tb.Passport = model.Passport;
                        tb.Sex = model.Sex;

                        context.tblInitialApplicantLevel2.Add(tb);


                        tblALResult results = new tblALResult();
                        results.Attempt = model.alResults.Attempt;
                        results.Grading = model.alResults.Grading;
                        results.IndexNo = model.alResults.IndexNo;
                        results.InitialApplicantLevel2ID = tb.InitialApplicantLevel2ID;
                        results.Stream = model.alResults.Stream;
                        results.Year = model.alResults.Year;
                        results.Medium = model.alResults.Medium;
                        results.ZScore = model.alResults.ZScore;

                        context.tblALResults.Add(results);


                        Save();


                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Update Record

```
public bool Update(InitialApplicantLevel2Model model)
        {
            try
            {
                using (context = new SIMSDBAPPEntities())
                {
                    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        var tb = (from tba in context.tblInitialApplicantLevel2
                                  where tba.InitialApplicantLevel2ID == model.InitialApplicantLevel2ID
                                  select tba).SingleOrDefault();

                        tb.NIC = model.NIC;
                        tb.Passport = model.Passport;
                        tb.Sex = model.Sex;

                        var results = (from tbr in context.tblALResults
                                       where tbr.InitialApplicantLevel2ID ==       model.InitialApplicantLevel2ID
                                       select tbr).SingleOrDefault();

                        results.Attempt = model.alResults.Attempt;
                        results.Grading = model.alResults.Grading;
                        results.IndexNo = model.alResults.IndexNo;
                        results.InitialApplicantLevel2ID = tb.InitialApplicantLevel2ID;
                        results.Stream = model.alResults.Stream;
                        results.Year = model.alResults.Year;
                        results.Medium = model.alResults.Medium;
                        results.ZScore = model.alResults.ZScore;

                        Save();


                        scope.Complete();


                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

View

```
<tr><td colspan="6"><hr /><b>G.C.E. (A/L) Results</b></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Year: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResults.Year)</td>
        <td>Index No: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResults.IndexNo)</td>
        <td>Medium: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResults.Medium)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stream: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResults.Stream)</td>
        <td>Attempt: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResults.Attempt)</td>
        <td>Zscore: </td>
        <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.alResults.ZScore)

        </td>
    </tr>
```

> Student details are inserting without an issue but the ALResults
>   properties are null. However, when updating a record ALResults object
>   properties get the values from view and update the record perfectly.
>   Why the object properties are null when inserting the record?

Comment: When creating record are you sure that `model.alResults` properties aren't nulls? Enable writing all MySQL commands to output in EFContext holding class if you use Entity Framework and see if there are any MySQL errors, serialization notices or if Create Table command has all properties.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as shown below.Use "virtual" with your "alResults" object.

```
public class InitialApplicantLevel2Model
    {
       //removed for clarity

        public virtual ALResults alResults { get; set; }

    }
```